# Try to select all text in TextBox when focus/clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, events, textbox, click

I try to imitate the behaviour when the user clicks on a username field (for example) and all the text (name) will be selected automatically to make easier to replace it with a new one. But when the user clicks again on the field the text/name turn unselected state, so the user can continue to write text from the cursor. I'm sure everybody know what I'm trying to describe as we all met this many times when we write in a text field or want to modify it's content...

So the issue is when I use the Enter focus event and apply SelectAll(), just not working at all! The text still not selected. I tried to use Click event too, which worked fine, but I got difficulties with the second click as all mouse click run the SelectAll() method again the text always still selected.. probably I could use global variables which store the selection state of the text and change states vica-versa, but I don't want to use any extra variable if don't necessary (each for all TextBox... nope).

There should be a simple and elegant solution for this as many-many application & website use this behaviour to make the users' life easier. I read a few forum and found some solution but they look unnecessarily more complex than I hoped.

This is the relevant part of my code... nothing special!

```
    private void G_tbx_canvasSize_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as TextBox).SelectAll();
    }
```

This should work on this way:

- User clicks on the TextBox (TB)
- TB focused
- The code run and select all the text
- User clicks again on TB
- As this already focused, the code won't run again so text unselect itself by default.. (I tested this!)
- If user clicks away and click on TB again, everything run again and again..

**Please help!** I can't figure out why this is occur any issue, it shouldn't be happen...

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to combine both Enter and Click events.  This code works for me (on a textbox named textBox2) when the handlers are wired up to the appropriate events:

```
private bool textBox2JustEntered = false;
private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.SelectAll();
    textBox2JustEntered = true;
}

private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2JustEntered)
    {
        textBox2.SelectAll();
    }

    textBox2JustEntered = false;
}
```

You want the click event to select all the text only if the textbox has just been entered.  The extra `SelectAll` call in the Enter event is there because, without it, the normal "select all the text when this control is tabbed to" behavior doesn't occur.

An alternative, as suggested by @jimi is to do the following:

```
private void textBox3_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => (sender as TextBox).SelectAll()));
}
```

This will post a call to `SelectAll` into the message queue for the form.  The associated code will run after all the message processing for the initial mouse-click is complete.

Comment: Just `BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> (sender as TextBox).SelectAll()));` in the `Enter` event.

Comment: `BeginInvoke` called on the UI Thread works in the UI Thread and there alone. MashaledInvoke takes care of that. No ThreadPool Thread is used (and I don't see why you think one should be involved). `BeginInvoke` called from the intended marshaler (the Form) just enqueues a message in the Message Loop (*asynchnonously* - you should not call `Invoke()` from the UI Thread).

Comment: I stand corrected.  So it is effectively a good old Win32 PostMessage call under the covers

Comment: Yes, exactly. After a couple of checks to verify that the Thread is the same, `PostMessage()` is called. Nothing more than that in this context.

Comment: Thanks guys! The 'BeginInvoke' stuff is working like a charm! Really easy solution, exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you should wait for the GotFocus event. Maybe it is better to react on the Enter event.

But even if you would do so, this wouldn't help, because after each of these events you get a TextBox.Click, which will have deselected your text.ou get the TextBox.Click event.

If you regularly use a TextBox with this special behaviour, consider to create a TextBoxWithSpecialClickBehaviour class derived from  TextBox, and override OnEnter and OnClick.

```
class TextBoxWithSpecialClickBehaviour : TextBox
{
    public bool SelectAllTextOnGetFocus {get; set;} = true;

    // TODO: override some default behaviour
}
```

Override OnEnter and OnClick

```
protected override void OnEnter (EventArgs e)
{
    // select all text
    if (this.SelectAllTextOnGetFocus)
        base.SelectAll();

     // raise the event
     base.OnEnter(e);
}
```

I think you should first Select the text, before others get notified. So if event handlers ask if the text is selected, they get the correct answer. Be aware though, that these event handlers might unselect the text again.

```
protected virtual void OnClick (EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.SelectAllTextOnGetFocus)
    {
        // if nothing selected: select all, if anything selected: deselect all
        if (base.SelectionLength = 0)
            base.SelectAll();
        else
            base.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
    base.OnClick();
}
```

Experiment a bit: override OnEnter, or OnGotFocus? Maybe you need to set TextBox.SelectionStart also.

If you plan not to reuse this TextBox several times, it is enough to react on the corresponding event.

By the way: are you sure you want this behaviour? What happens if a user clicks, then starts editing and he clicks somewhere in the edited text because he wants to select some text to copy-paste it to a different part of the text he is editing.

- Text ABCDEFG
- Click on the TextBox **ABCDEFG** completely selected
- Click between C and D: nothing selected
- Drag the mouse to the F: ABC**DEF**G selected
- Ctrl C to copy the text. Must the text still be selected?
- Click between A and B in order to Paste the text.
- Because of the click **ABCDEFG** completely selected

Are you sure you want this? Do operators expect this?